# Show that $\underset{E: \mu(E)<\delta}{\sup} \underset{j}{\sup} \displaystyle\int_E |f_j|d\mu \geq \epsilon.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

Let $f \in L_1(X, \mu)$. Show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $E \in M$ with $\mu(E) < \delta$, then

$$\int_E |f| d\mu < \epsilon.$$

Then, find $(X,\mu)$ and a sequence $\{f_j\}\subset L_1 (X,\mu)$ for which there exists $\epsilon >0$

$$\sup_{E: \mu(E)<\delta} \sup_{j} \int_E |f_j|d\mu \geq \epsilon.$$

**Proof:**

Fix $\epsilon >0$, then we can find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\int_X f_n -f < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Choose $\delta =\frac{\epsilon}{2 n}$ Let $E \subset X$ such that $\mu (E) <\delta$. Then we can argue as follows

$$\int_E f \leq \int_E f_n + \int_E f_n-f \leq \int_E f_n + \int_X f_n-f$$

$$\int_E f \leq n \mu(E)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$$

I have no clue how to solve the other part. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with a sequence of constant functions for $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Basically the condition that you’ve proven is known as “no escape to vertical infinity” and you think about why. If you want to come up with an example for the second part, you need to find a sequence that gets bigger and bigger over some smaller and smaller set.

Comment: Statement of the secomd part is incomplete. You  did not say what $\delta$ is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably $\delta>0$ in the last statement of the OP's is one positive number for which $$\int_E|f|\,d\mu<\varepsilon\qquad\text{if}\qquad \mu(E)<\delta$$

In such case, it suffices to consider a probability function and construct a sequence $X_n$ of random variables which is not uniformly integrable.

For example $([0,1],\mathscr{B}([0,1]),m)$ where $m$ is Lebesgue's measure.  Let $f\in L_1([0,1],m)$. As the OP already checked, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that
\begin{align}\int_A|f|\,dm<\varepsilon\qquad\text{whenever}\qquad m(A)<\delta\tag{0}\label{zero}
\end{align}
Consider $f_n(t)=x_n\mathbb{1}_{[0,1/n]}(x)$ where $x_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$ is to be determined.

Set $\varepsilon=1$, and fix $\delta>0$ for which \eqref{zero} holds. For all $n>\delta^{-1}$,
$m\big(|f_n|>\max(1,\delta^{-1})\big)=m([0,1/n])=\frac1n<\delta$. Hence
$$\sup_{\substack{E\in\mathscr{B}([0,1])\\m(E)<\delta}}\sup_n\int_E|f_n|\,dm\geq\sup_n\int_{\{|f_n|>\max(1,\delta^{-1})\}}|f_n|\,dm=\sup_n\frac{x_n}{n}$$

The sequence $x_n$ can be taken so be $x_n=2n$ for example.